# splitting string with regular expression in php using preg_split

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regular expression (using `preg_split()`) that can be used to split the following string:

```
hello<span id="more-32"></span>world
```

Desired result:

```
$var[0]=hello 
$var[1]=world
```

I tried using this code put it didn't work

```
preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"></span>/','hello<span id="more-32"></span>world')
```

Comment: Why not simply [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: Regex isn't always the answer.

Comment: because i need the result to be back in array and i need to know what is before the span and what is after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You should escape the fore slash by a backslash.

Second: You should put the semicolon at the end of code.

This will work:

```
    <?php
    $string = 'hello<span id="more-32"></span>world';
    $pattern = '/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/';

    $out = preg_split($pattern,$string);

?>
```

Print the splitted string:

```
    foreach ($out as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />'; 
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

or:

```
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array (
     [0] => hello 
     [1] => world 
)
```